# Is my Bitcoin address valid for mining?

Tags: mining-theory, block, mining-reward, coinbase-transaction

I am looking at the specific block at height [680175](https://btc.com/00000000000000000004dbd66fa71fdcd62658bf8c8e2e153521257ad5858c71?page=1&order_by=tx_block_idx&asc=1).

When comparing the address which received the block reward

```
# bitcoin-cli validateaddress 1KFHE7w8BhaENAswwryaoccDb6qcT6DbYY
{
  "isvalid": true,
  "address": "1KFHE7w8BhaENAswwryaoccDb6qcT6DbYY",
  "scriptPubKey": "76a914c825a1ecf2a6830c4401620c3a16f1995057c2ab88ac",
  "isscript": false,
  "iswitness": false
}
```

to my newly generated address

```
# bitcoin-cli validateaddress bc1q403w7zrj74azzunk89srt2m3vuajatlmskcktm
{
  "isvalid": true,
  "address": "bc1q403w7zrj74azzunk89srt2m3vuajatlmskcktm",
  "scriptPubKey": "0014abe2ef0872f57a217276396035ab71673b2eaffb",
  "isscript": false,
  "iswitness": true,
  "witness_version": 0,
  "witness_program": "abe2ef0872f57a217276396035ab71673b2eaffb"
}
```

there are some differences in the scriptPubKey and the witness program. Are these differences relevant for mining?

The inferred PubKey hash of the miner address is `c825a1ecf2a6830c4401620c3a16f1995057c2ab`. Would my PubKey hash be `abe2ef0872f57a217276396035ab71673b2eaffb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a miner finds a valid block, the coinbase transaction they included in their block pays out the mining reward to their own address. Mining rewards can be sent to any type of output. The only special restriction on coinbase transaction outputs is that they can only be spent after a maturation period of 100 confirmations.

You are looking at two different address types:

- `bc1q403w7zrj74azzunk89srt2m3vuajatlmskcktm` is a Pay to Witness Public Key Hash (P2WPKH) address
- `1KFHE7w8BhaENAswwryaoccDb6qcT6DbYY` is a Pay to Public Key Hash
  (P2PKH) address.

P2WPKH addresses are the more block weight efficient successor of P2PKH addresses. Spending funds received to P2WPKH addresses takes less than half the blockweight as spending funds received to P2PKH addresses.

> The inferred PubKey hash of the miner address is `c825a1ecf2a6830c4401620c3a16f1995057c2ab`. Would my PubKey hash be `abe2ef0872f57a217276396035ab71673b2eaffb`?

Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, can I use my PubKey hash for a P2PKH output in the first output of the coinbase transaction? .. according to the example in the TxOut section in https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/transactions.html

Comment: Yes, you could use the same pubkey either for a P2WPKH or a P2PKH. I don't quite understand why you're asking like this, though. You could just pay out to a P2WPKH address instead as well.